# Any Examples of in depth Angular-2 routing using dart?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

Does anyone have a complete example  using CanActivate and CanDeactivate routing in an Angular-2 app? The official documentation for dart isn't complete yet and I can't seem to put all the pieces together from the typescript examples.

Comment: Maybe you've already seen them, but https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/angular-2-authentication-revisited-611bf7373bf9#.9h0n5psoy has some pretty good typescript examples in the "Restricting access" section which might help.

Comment: @on3al what do you need? what could I explain?